# libreoffice /open office calc - visualise formula

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet

Let's say I have two alternatives in columns `C,D` like so:

```
row  6: sample size
row  7: sample mean
row  8: sample standard deviation
```

and then want to do a t-Test, which requires (amongst other things) calculating the degrees of freedom

```
C13 =( POWER( POWER(C8,2)/C6 + POWER(D8,2)/D6 ,2) )   /   ( POWER( POWER(C8,2)/C6 ,2)/(C6+1) + POWER( POWER(D8,2)/D6 ,2)/(D6+1) ) - 2
     (degrees of freedom)
```

where I have copied this obnoxious formula out of a book which provides them in nice, human-readable format, of course.

[image]

Let me put it like this: it looks correct when I stare at it for long enough, but no amount of staring will convince me that I haven't missed a mistake.

Is there a way to print this (libre office) formula in a more readable way for verification?

Comment: One way to verify is to start from the Calc formula and work backwards.  This is what I came up with using a text editor that matches parentheses:  `(sa^2/na + sb^2/nb)^2 / ( (sa^2/na)^2 / (na+1) + (sb^2/nb)^2 / (nb+1) ) - 2`.  This agrees with the formula from the book, so it seems correct.  However there could be some other spreadsheet problem.  Can you provide any example input and expected output values?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to print this (libre office) formula in a more readable way for verification?

My recommended tool : use notepad++

It'll highlight and match the opening and the closing brackets "(" & ")".